Validation error for "Send Email" action in a Screen Flow
I can usually troubleshoot and debug this stuff but I'm at my wit's end.
I have tried everything. I have stripped the 'Send Email' action down to literally the bare minimum. I've tried multiple text templates as well as just entering text straight into the body. I've tried every combination of activated fields. NOTHING IS WORKING. Same error every time:
The "PR" element in your flow has validation errors.

EDIT Back with screenies. I should mention though I think this is an email issue. I ran a few other flows in debug that I KNOW were sending email just last week, and the succeed but aren't sending anything.
screenie 1

Scratch that. Got email working and still getting error

Hi. I feel your frustration, but it would really help if you could [edit] the question to include the details of your "PR" element and details of the flow itself.

@PhilW yeah good point. Will do asap

I do not think the email is to blame here. Without seeing your flow, I am not able to confirm, but there is an element somewhere in your flow called "PR".
This can be a decision element or a screen element or any other flow element. When you click on it in the flow builder, it will highlight some issue with regards to inputs, or an API name that isn't provided etc.
Once that issue is resolved, you will be able successfully debug and activate the flow.
I replicated your error by providing incorrect input to the Get Element called "PR":

BillingLatitude is a number, but I gave it a boolean value, which is incorrect.
When I debug the flow, I get the same error message as you:

Good luck!
